# /Lua/ How to do this (idk how to call that lol)

Tags: lua, numbers, roblox

I need to make a trolleybus number, which won't repeat for game. For example, there is a number "101" and there musn't be more "101". How to do that? I have a code, but I know, he won't work and I won't test it lol

```
function giveNumber()
local number = math.random(100, 199)
local takedNumbers = {}
local i = 0
local massiv = i+1
script.Parent.pered.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = number
script.Parent.zad.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = number
script.Parent.levo.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = number
script.Parent.pravo.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = number

takedNumbers[massiv] = {number}
end 
script.Parent.Script:giveNumber() // what I wrote here? idk...

if number == takedNumbers[massiv] then 
    giveNumber()
end
```

i didn't test it, because I think it won't work because this code is something bad

Comment: Have I understood it correctly that you're trying to generate a unique number each time?

Comment: If you want a set of choices to always remove one from, I have implemented that in Lua: https://the-algorithms.com/de/algorithm/choiceset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will serve your needs.

In the function `generateUniqueNumber`, the script loops until it found a number that is not yet in the array. (in other words, that it hasn't given out yet)

Once it found that number, it will insert it into the table to remember that it has given it out, and then it will return the number.

Then on the bottom of the script we just give the numbers to the buses :-)

```lua
--[[
    Goal: Give all buses a unique number
]] 

-- Variables
local takenNumbers = {};

-- This function returns a random number in the range [100, 199] that has not been taken yet
function generateUniqueNumber()
    local foundNumber = false;

    while not foundNumber do
        randomNumber = math.random(100, 199);

        if not table.find(takenNumbers, randomNumber) then
            table.insert(takenNumbers, randomNumber);
            return randomNumber;
        end
    end
end

-- This function sets the number of the bus
script.Parent.pered.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = tostring(generateUniqueNumber());
script.Parent.zad.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = tostring(generateUniqueNumber());
script.Parent.levo.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = tostring(generateUniqueNumber());
script.Parent.pravo.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text = tostring(generateUniqueNumber());
```

2 things:

1. I didn't test this code as Roblox is not installed on the pc I'm currently on.
2. Please try formatting your code nicely next time. It greatly improves the readability! For example, you can use this website:
   https://codebeautify.org/lua-beautifier

Comment: You usually don't need semicolons in Lua(u). In this case it is safe to omit all of them. It would also be more efficient to store the numbers in a hash set rather than a list. You could then use `takenNumbers[randomNumber]` to determine whether you've already had a number, which runs in constant time. You also don't need the `foundNumber` variable; a `while true` will work just fine. The idiomatic looping construct for this would be `repeat`-`until`.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler

Fill a table with free numbers...

```
local freenumbers = {}
for i = 1, 99 do freenumbers[i] = i + 100 end
```

...for every new `takennumbers` use `table.remove()` on `freenumbers`

```
local takennumbers = {}
if #freenumbers > 0 then
  takennumbers[#takennumbers + 1] = table.remove(freenumbers, math.random(1, #freenumbers))
end
```